# proc fastclus to calculate new seeds for proc cluster

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using fastclus in SAS to use the final seeds for proc cluster/fastclus in for initial seed selection.please let me know the option available for that in sas

Answer (score 0):

If you want proc fastclus to recalculate the seed of the cluster for each iteration you can use the drift option. You can read up about options in proc fastclus here

http://www.math.wpi.edu/saspdf/stat/chap27.pdf